# Intersection of two convex sets

Tags: convex-geometry

Let $A$ and $B$ be disjoint finite subsets of $\mathbb{R}^d$ for some $d$. Furthermore, assume that $|A\cup B|\geq d+3$, $conv(A)\cap conv(B)\neq\emptyset$, and points in $A\cup B$ are in general position, i.e., any $d+1$ points of them are affinely independent. Prove that there exist $A^{'}\subseteq A$ and $B^{'}\subseteq B$ such that $|A^{'}|+|B^{'}|= d+2$ and $conv(A^{'})\cap conv(B^{'})\neq\emptyset$.

Note:  This is not a homework. I am just reading a paper. I did not understand one of the claims which I write here as a problem above.

I just proved that $\dim (conv(A)\cap conv(B))\geq 1$, maybe it could be useful!

Comment: Please add your thoughts on this question. Also it would be nice to see some words regarding [Radon's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Radon%27s_theorem) in this post, since it is pretty similar to your question.

Comment: Also, might be relevant: [how do I ask homework questions?](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1803/how-to-ask-a-homework-question)

Comment: Did you try to use Caratheodory's theorem?

Comment: @szw17101: I think with Carathedeory's theorem just we can assume that the size of $A$ and $B$ are less than or equal $d+1$.

Comment: Or... an element of $conv(A)\cap conv(B)$ is a convex combination of at most $d+1$ points from $A\cup B$. Take $A_1$ the set of these points from $A$ and $B_1$ similarly. If convex hulls of them do intersect, we are done. If not... we have at least two additional points. 

This is my attempt only. I don't know whether it is good...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This a direct consequence of Kirchberger's theorem which states: Let $A$ and $B$ be finite sets in $\mathbb{R}^n$ such that,
for every subset $C$ of $n + 2$ or fewer points of $A\cup B$, the sets $A\cap C$ and $B\cap C$ can be strictly separated. Then $A$ and $B$ can be strictly separated.